# What do Sponsors actually do?

Tags: blood-bowl-2

In Blood Bowl 2 you can upgrade your stadium, and there is an option to sign a sponsorship contract.

Each contract gives a brief rundown of the company which always includes some kind of vague negative/description of what they expect.

For example: Orcidas (probably the clearest)

> *The well known brand encourages friendly competition and team spiirt. Just remember that for them, a match never becomes really
>   friendly until the moment that everyone has lost teeth.*

I assume this means I will get a bonus if I inflict a lot of casualties or something? However, there is no actual mechanical description of what you get or what you need to do.

I've had a rummage on the official forums, and all I have found are some references to "maybe they will have some kind of mini-quest thing that relates to the company".

Has anyone got some data or official word on what the actual effects are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment... nothing.

They are used in the solo player campaign but in the regular game they are just a cosmetic change to add flavor to your team.

They may have more functionality added in the future but it hasn't happened yet.